# Which of the two SELECT statements is faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

It seems that the second statement applies the where condition first before joining and the first one does join before applying the where condition, so the second one would be faster because it would do less joining. But is that really the case? Is there a reference which says definitely that in the first statement the where condition is executed after all the other joining operations finish?

```
SELECT * FROM class t1 
  LEFT JOIN class_students t2 ON t1.id = t2.class_id 
  LEFT JOIN student t3 ON t2.student_id = t3.id 
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM class WHERE id = 1) t1 
  LEFT JOIN class_students t2 ON t1.id = t2.class_id 
  LEFT JOIN student t3 ON t2.student_id = t3.id;
```

Comment: The compiler breaks down your SQL statement and chooses what the optimizer thinks is fastest. If you look at the execution plan, it might actually reveal the exact same plan.

Comment: Lfet isn't a recognised command

Answer (score 0):

Your second option has a "derived table" (a subquery in `FROM` or `JOIN`).  Subqueries *usually* take extra effort.  So, *usually* it is better to avoid them.

In your particular example, the Optimizer will *probably* start with t1 because the `WHERE` clause mentions it.  That is, the execution will filter based on `t1.id = 1`, just as you suggest the second version would do.

Note my italicized words...  There are exceptions to my statements; if you find a case where the second version runs faster, present it, I may be able to explain why it runs faster.  (A *likely* example is where the subquery has `GROUP BY` and/or `LIMIT`.  This is different enough from `WHERE` to make a difference.)